# FastAPI jsonencoder always returns camelCase instead of snake_case

Tags: python, fastapi

I have a data object in snake_case and a database schema which uses snake_case. I simply want to create a new row in a database. In order to do that I have to serialise the data object first. Unfortunately, when I use the default fastAPI serialiser I always get back a camelCase object. Of course, I could use another lib to transform the serialised camelCase data into snake_case again but there must be a simpler way.

```py
class CRUDPost(CRUDBase[Post, PostCreate, PostUpdate]):
    def create(self, db: Session, obj_in: PostCreate, created_by: UUID4) -> Post:
        logger.info(obj_in) // => obj in snake_case
        obj_in_data = jsonable_encoder(obj_in, by_alias=True)
        logger.info(obj_in_data) => obj in camelCase
        db_obj = self.model(**obj_in_data, created_by=created_by)
        db.add(db_obj)
        db.commit()
        db.refresh(db_obj)
        return db_obj
```

EDIT:

Object in Camelcase:`{'leetcodeSubmissions': 0, 'interviewTimeline': 0}`
Object in snake_case: `{'leetcode_submissions': 0, 'interview_timeline': 0}`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If my guess is correct then it is expected behaviour of `jsonable_encoder`.

Based on this line:
`obj_in_data = jsonable_encoder(obj_in, by_alias=True)`

I think your `PostCreate` has set aliases for its fields which are camelCase and you are invoking `jsonable_encoder` on Pydantic Model which will convert the class'es instance to Python dictionary. Try setting `by_alias` to `False` and it should fix your issue.